# How to setup GPU to crack WPA or WPA2 faster using pyrit in kali linux

Tags: wpa2, gpu

I have a Dell M5040 notebook which comes with

AMD Dual-Core E-450 64-bit Processor(1.65 GHz) with AMD Radeon HD 6320 Graphics

4 GB RAM 
 500 GB HDD

I want to use it for cracking my home wifi network with Kali Linux using pyrit

I have captured wpa handshake and to crack it in less time I want to increase speed of cracking using  CPU+GPU  or AMD HD Radeon 6320 which comes with my notebook

How can I do this?

Please help.

Sorry for bad english

Comment: I don't get why is the question down voted. Can anybody help me?

Comment: It looks like you have not done much research. Step 1: Read pyrit tutorial. https://code.google.com/p/pyrit/wiki/Tutorial

Answer (score -1):

This is not what you're looking for, but there's a few websites that will crack the hashes for you, and some are free. There's one where you can search previously cracked hashes:

http://www.hashkiller.co.uk